# Cant access view through direct URL [Maven]

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm creating my first project in Maven, and already have a noob problem.

In my WEB-INF folder, I have another folder called "classes", in that folder I have a view called "view.jsp".

When I try to access the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectenIIJavaWeb/classes/view
```

I get a Http 404 not found error.

This is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Java's WEB-INF does not work like a htdocs/ directory, i.e. your URL should rather look like http://localhost:8080/ProjectenIIJavaWeb/view.jsp

Answer (score 0):

1. You have configured the DispatcherServlet only for the url pattern *.htm. So you have to call a URL with that pattern, otherwise there is no servlet which matches your request.
2. As the name says, the folder "classes" is for Java classes. Resources should be in the root of the WAR file.
3. You don't call your view, you define request mappings and let Spring MVC handle the view resolution. I suggest to read the Spring MVC documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc)

Answer (score 0):

In case you plan to keep your jsp's(without exposing the detailed path of actual file) inside WEB-INF this should help

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>  
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>  
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>  
</bean>
```

Detailed example: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internalresourceviewresolver-example/